# ngrok with websocket does not work, Sec-WebSocket-Accept not found

Tags: websocket, ngrok, esp-idf

I have a webserver that sits behind ****.ngrok.io that works when i connect to it through ws://****.ngrok.io/ws/ with websocket.org

I also have a device that can connect to either my webserver or the echo.websocket.org server.

Why is it that when i connect my device to ws://****.ngrok.io/ws/ I get a "TRANSPORT_WS: Sec-WebSocket-Accept not found", but this does not happen when i use echo.websocket.org. I've changed nothing to my device (embedded board using ESP-IDF) other than the address.

is there a setting missing in my ngrok? my cmdline is ./ngrok http http://0.0.0.0:8000
In the ngrok terminal, it doesn't look like it even detected a GET /ws/ connection, it remains blank.

interestingly, if i remove my /ws/ path in my device, ngrok is able to see a connection but it is routed wrong (because my server uses /ws/ path for websocket)

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to test on ws://broker.emqx.io on port 8083.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ngrok for WebSocket, you should use the 'tcp' parameter because WebSocket operates on TCP, not HTTP.

```
ngrok tcp http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

Use the generated URL and replace 'tcp://' with 'ws://'.
WebSocket functions as a server and is not accessed through HTTP.

Comment: This works for insecure ws, as the TCP becomes a dumb router (I guess) for the socket (which is http, upgrading to websocket), but now we use TLS/SSL...